# When zero-divisor graph is planar?

Tags: graph-theory

I need specific conditions that are completely exhausted  class of Rings zero divisors graph of which are planar.
Thank you.

Comment: Since you're new, I'd like to give you some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are**. That way, people won't tell you stuff you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help if you show that you've tried yourself.

Comment: [This](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0021869303003703/1-s2.0-S0021869303003703-main.pdf?_tid=09da11d6-e745-11e2-a7b4-00000aab0f02&acdnat=1373229628_c1b775ff6518b5e15040035fdb4611b8) gives a full characterization in the case of  _finite_ rings and some conditions for non-planarity in the _infinite_ case.